# Swift class "does not implement (objc) protocol"

Tags: objective-c, swift, interop, protocols

I'm having trouble making a Swift `NSManagedObject` subclass conform to an Objective-C protocol.

I've created a model protocol in order to abstract somewhat my Core Data models from other components in my app which have no business knowing these things are Core Data Managed Objects...

So I have a protocol as follows:

```
@protocol UserProtocol <NSObject>

@property (nonatomic) NSSet *friends;

@end
```

And my managed object subclass in swift is:

```
class User: NSManagedObject, UserProtocol {

    @NSManaged var friends: Set<User>

}
```

Unfortunately I am being told `User` does not conform to `UserProtocol`. I can't find a way to see the swift interpretation of my Objective-C protocol, is there a way to do that? If I can see that I could work out why my swift class isn't matching the protocol.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you need getters and setters? Also, is `var Set` not equivalent to `NSMutableSet`?

Comment: `@NSManaged` requires `var`. You've got a point though maybe Set resolves to NSMutableSet. So isn't there a way to get a Swift view on an Objective-C piece of code?

Comment: Which Xcode version are you using? In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3.2) `NSSet` is mapped to `Set<NSObject>`, so you would have to define the property as `@NSManaged var friends: Set<NSObject>` to satisfy the protocol.

Comment: Thank you, that did fix it. I guess this will all be a lot nicer to work with in Swift 2.0 with Objective-C generics. Please answer the question and I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift 1.2 (Xcode 6.3.2) `NSSet` is mapped to `Set<NSObject>`, so you would have to define the property as

```
@NSManaged var friends: Set<NSObject>
```

to satisfy the protocol. In Swift 2 you can define the Objective-C
protocol method using "lightweight generics".